# Rake task to create a Rails partial from json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rake

Right now I have a helper:

```
def blog_posts
  Rails.cache.fetch("blog_posts", :expires_in => 30.minutes) do
    url = URI('http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/blog/?json=get_recent_posts')
    request = Net::HTTP.get(url)
    response = JSON.parse(request)
    response['posts'].take(4)
  end
rescue => e
  logger.error "Error retrieving blog posts!"
  logger.error "#{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
  []
end
```

And the view I have:

```
<% blog_posts.each do |blog| %>
  <div class="col col-3">
    <a class="search-page-links" href="<%= blog['url'] %>" target="_blank">
      <img class="post-image" src="<%= blog['thumbnail'] %>">
      <br/><br/>
      <%= blog['title'].html_safe %>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which works fine. Except we dont want the data to be pulled when the page loads at all anymore, because we cant always count on the source. The plan is to add a Rake task to the deploy process so that static data can be updated in a rails partial at each deploy, which would be rendered into the view. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I would suggest you store the fetched data in your database, instead. Updating your application codebase every time you want to update this view seems like a pain.

Comment: Let's say database isn't an option right now (not "my" application, not my rules sort of situation). We deploy daily and this partial would only actually change weekly because the 'recent posts' aren't frequent. So we wouldn't deploy TO update the partial. Instead WHEN we deploy we'd like a partial to update IF there happens to be changes/updates with the posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I did**

Rake Task:

```
namespace :blog do

  task :pull do
    tmp = "tmp/blog_posts"

    def fetch_blog_posts
      json = open('http://www.xxxxx.com/blog/?json=get_recent_posts').read
      hash = JSON.parse(json)
      hash['posts'].take(4)
    end

    def download_blog_images
      fetch_blog_posts.each_with_index do |blog, index|
        File.open("tmp/#{index}.jpg", 'wb') do |f|
          f.write open("#{blog['thumbnail']}").read
        end
        puts "Downloaded #{(index.to_i+1).ordinalize} Image" 
      end
    end

    def retrieve_blog_data
      puts 'Retrieving blog data from Wordpress'
      fetch_blog_posts

      File.open("tmp/blog_posts.json", "w+") do |f|
        f.write(JSON.pretty_generate(fetch_blog_posts))
        puts 'Saved json data'
      end
      download_blog_images
    end

    retrieve_blog_data
    puts 'Done retrieving blog posts'
  end

end
```

Helper:

```
module BlogHelper

  def blog_posts
    if Rails.env.development?
      json = open('http://xxxxx/blog/?json=get_recent_posts').read
    else
      json = File.read("tmp/blog_posts.json")
    end
    hash = JSON.parse(json)
    hash['posts'].take(4)
  end

end
```

Controller:

```
def home
  @blog_posts = blog_posts
end
```

View:

```
<% @blog_posts.each_with_index do |blog, index| %>
  # markup for each post...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating partials just sound like the worst possible solution because you are creating a huge amount of code duplication, and potentially a huge slug (deployed code base). If you have to then save the JSON data to disk and use fragment caching if needed.

Other alternatives would be to use a key/value or JSON based storage instead of storing the data in your codebase (which is almost always a bad idea).

I would sit down with the client or whoever is making up the rules and explain that it would be a pretty big maintenance problem down the line and suggest a solution that is actually tenable.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I totally agree with you. However, my question is still unanswered. Even If I choose to take one of several other more sensible approaches, the question still remains. I want to know how one could do this. If we pretend today is a holiday where we are supposed to find ways to do things the way they shouldn't be done, and me figuring this out is my participation in the holiday, would that help? Because I'm looking for an answer to my actual question.

Comment: Well it would probably involve rendering a master view with data in it and writing the resulting HTML to disk. You would want to look at how `rspec-rails` renders views (and partials) in isolation in view specs. And then you need to do the same for whatever template links to the partials.

Comment: Its probably going to take 10 times as long as doing it like a sane person. But hey - its your holiday.

Comment: cool ill investigate rspec-rails and see what goes on in there. If the world crashes and burns around me, i'll at least be able to deliver what was asked of me and demonstrate the 'why's' and 'why not's'. Happy holidays! :)

Comment: Its somewhere in here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/tree/master/lib/rspec/rails